# Cannot submit form from linked page in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, forms, jquery-mobile

I am trying to submit a form using jQuery Mobile, but if the form is on a linked page it will not submit. For example, my home page is `mysite.com/page.html`. If I put the form code on that page, the form submits perfectly. If I put the form on a different `data-role="page"` in the same file, the page's link becomes `mysite.com/#reg` and the submit button stops working entirely. I am using jQuery 1.8.3 and jQuery Mobile 1.2.0.

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uj68M/) with the form only on the Registration page. You'll notice that it doesn't do anything when submit is clicked. [Here's that exact same code](http://jsfiddle.net/h7apJ/1/), just with the form copy-pasted onto the main page. When submit is clicked on this one, a loading screen is given (meaning it's trying to submit but it's not finding my validation script).

Comment: Check this out | http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/docs/pages/docs-pages.html | Did you try by disabling ajax?

Comment: "It's important to note if you are linking from a mobile page that was loaded via Ajax to a page with multiple internal pages, you need to add a rel="external" or data-ajax="false" to the link. This tells the framework to do a full page reload to clear out the Ajax hash in the URL. This is critical because Ajax pages use the hash (#) to track the Ajax history, while multiple internal pages use the hash to indicate internal pages so there will be a conflicts."

Comment: I appreciate it, but I did try that and it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close your first form tag.
After repair everything's working as expected.

Placed a fixed version here:

```
<form action="login.php" method="POST">
    <a href="#index" data-role="button" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">
        Return to home page
    </a>
<!-- The closing form tag -->
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JVXEa/

Comment: Oh my gosh, I can't believe it was as simple as that. Thank you so much!